# Gradle JAR: order of dependency jars and actual classes

Tags: java, ant, jar, gradle

My build.gradle:

```
jar {
    dependsOn configurations.runtime
    from { configurations.runtime.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }

    manifest {
        attributes(
            'Main-Class': 'com.company.product.veryNiceMainClass'
        )
    }
}
```

I want to tell Gradle to pick the dependency JARs first, then the actual implementation classes when creating a JAR, possibly overwriting some things. It is a must for the actual project. I did some RTFM but didn't help. You can do this in ant:

```
<target name="dist">
    <!-- deps first -->     
    <jar destfile="${dist.dir}/${ant.project.name}-${build.version}.jar">
        <zipgroupfileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*-jar-*.jar" />
        <zipgroupfileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*-bundle-*.jar" />
        <zipgroupfileset dir="${basedir}/lib-old" includes="**/*.jar" />
    </jar>
    <!-- classes, UPDATE (!) the JAR -->
    <jar destfile="${dist.dir}/${ant.project.name}-${build.version}.jar" update="true">
        <fileset dir="${build.classes.dir}" />
    </jar>
</target>
```

Any ideas?

Edit: Solution verified (thanks Ingo). Just define multiple from statements, in the order of your wish.

```
from { configurations.runtime.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } } // deps
from sourceSets.main.output.classesDir // classes
from 'log4j.properties' // some file
```

Comment: Try multiple `from` statements analogous to your `zipgroupfileset` entries

Comment: OK, I have added this as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define multiple `from` statements for the `jar` task, the resulting files will be processed in the that order.